# SQL Order By query problem

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with following dataset

```
id   name  parent  
------------------
1    xyz   NULL  
2    def   NULL  
3    mno   abc  
4    abc   NULL  
5    pqr   abc  
6    qfx   def
```

I would want to fetch the data in the following order:

```
1    abc   NULL  
3    mno   abc  
5    pqr   abc  
2    def   NULL  
6    qfx   def  
4    xyz   NULL
```

What I mean is ORDERing has to occur by Username but records with same parent must show together and just below the record for the parent.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this new answer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
ORDER BY
    CONCAT(parent, name)
```

it concatenated the two strings so it should order like this:

```
abc
abcmno
abcpqr
def
defqfx
xyz
```

Comment: The problem is that it assumes 'name' is alphabetically greater than 'parent' when ordering. If name is less, the sorting doesn't occur as expected.

Comment: I guess u meant name instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not necessarily *exactly* like this):

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
ORDER BY COALESCE(CONCAT(parent, '.'), '') + name
```

I would actually try to replace `'.'` with a character that is unlikely to appear in the names.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
Select * from table_name
    Order by
        name, parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not a problem at all? catch it:

```
select * from mytable order by parent, name
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you have is you want 2 rather different aspects. You want it in username order, but if there is a matching parent you want to group it.

The most obvious would be

```
select username, parent from mytable
order by parent,username
group by parent
```

But that still sorts it by parent first.

Im sure its possible to get exactly what you wanted, but, I havent had the caffine yet to work out an easy full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other in Oracle I have found it necessary to write Stored Proc to do hierarchical ordering.  Some RDBMSes offer CTE (common table expressions) which can acheive the same result.  I am not familiar with mySql and don't know what support it has but the following may help.

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_query)

[mySql specific](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Also Google "Joe Celko Trees and Hierarchies"